# regex to check datetime with a runtime exception

Tags: c#, php, regex

```
@"(Sun|Mon|Tue|Wed|Thu|Fri|Sat)\,((31(?!\ (Feb(ruary)?|Apr(il)?|June?|(Sep(?=\b|t)t?|Nov)(ember)?)))|((30|29)(?!\ Feb(ruary)?))|(29(?=\ Feb(ruary)?\ (((1[6-9]|[2-9]\d)(0[48]|[2468][048]|[13579][26])|((16|[2468][048]|[3579][26])00)))))|(0?[1-9])|1\d|2[0-8])\ (Jan(uary)?|Feb(ruary)?|Mar(ch)?|Apr(il)?|Jul(y)?)|Aug(ust)?|Oct(ober)?|(Sep(?=\b|t)t?|Nov|Dec)(ember)?)\((1[6-9]|[2-9]\d)\d{2})\s(20|21|22|23|[0-1]?\d):[0-5]?\d:[0-5]?\d"
```

Hello, I use it to check for datetime formated as

```
Thu, 10 Nov 2010 13:08:06
```

I have runtime exception stating that is an invalid regex.

Comment: I believe you have a mismatched parenthesis. There are 38 ( and 39 ).

Comment: What does PHP have anything to do with this question?

Comment: @KennyTM, Regex is used in php too.

Comment: @BabyDolphin - Regex is used in dozens of languages. The relevant question is: Which language are *you* using?

Answer (score 4):

You should use [`DateTime.TryParse()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9h21f14e.aspx). It's more suited to your needs.

Comment: Damn. I didn't even see the php tag.

Comment: Using a regular expression to validate a datetime is insane.

Answer (score 1):

Since you've tagged this with PHP...

You could use `strtotime();` to convert the string to a timestamp, then create the date required in the correct format, as follows:

`date("D, j M Y H:i:s", strtotime("Thu, 10 Nov 2010 13:08:06"));`

Then at least however it is written, it will be converted correctly (belongs as the date is (of course) valid.

Just an alternative to regex....

Answer (score 0):

This compiles :

```
Regex regexObj = new Regex(@"(Sun|Mon|Tue|Wed|Thu|Fri|Sat),((31(?! (Feb(ruary)?|Apr(il)?|June?|(Sep(?=\b|t)t?|Nov)(ember)?)))|((30|29)(?! Feb(ruary)?))|(29(?= Feb(ruary)? (((1[6-9]|[2-9]\d)(0[48]|[2468][048]|[13579][26])|((16|[2468][048]|[3579][26])00)))))|(0?[1-9])|1\d|2[0-8]) (Jan(uary)?|Feb(ruary)?|Mar(ch)?|Apr(il)?|Jul(y)?)|Aug(ust)?|Oct(ober)?|(Sep(?=\b|t)t?|Nov|Dec)(ember)?\((1[6-9]|[2-9]\d)\d{2}\s(20|21|22|23|[0-1]?\d):[0-5]?\d:[0-5]?\d");
```

You have a couple of two many `)`. Other than that, good luck debugging this mess..